# issues with splitting the screen using LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have encountered an issue while splitting the screen using a linearLayout,
My target is to split it into 9 Pisces -
When I started playing with the LinearLayout I have came to the following result:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/4/firstna.png/

with the following xml code:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:baselineAligned="false">
    <FrameLayout
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:background="#aa0000"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:background="#00aa00"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="4"/>
    <FrameLayout
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:background="#aaaa00"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

later on when I tried to add content to the left FrameLayout it changed the ratio of this FrameLayout (which Is the problem..):

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/692/secondp.png/

using the following code:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:baselineAligned="false">
  <FrameLayout
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:background="#aa0000"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1">
      <LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1">
<TextView
    android:text="row one"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<TextView
    android:text="row two"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<TextView
    android:text="row three"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<TextView
    android:text="row four"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:background="#00aa00"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="4"/>
    <FrameLayout
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:background="#aaaa00"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I would like to have the ability to control the layouts just with the layout_weight attribute - if adding content to the FrameLayout changes its ratio I would need your help finding another container that the ratio will be saved in.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow you're using a lot of nested layouts! Does your lefthand layout need to be a frame layout with another linearlayout inside it and then all the textviews? Or can you just replace the FrameLayout parent and move the background color to the vertical LinearLayout?

Actually come to that, why do you need the 2nd linear layout too? You could just specify that the first linear layout has an orientation of horizontal (you have fill_parent on the height anyway) and then drop the second nested linear layout.

Also you should probably consider changing the layout width of the FrameLayouts to 0dp so that they get resized dynamically based on the weight.